# How to add a menu link to the far right of the menu

Tags: html, css

I want to add a simple Menu Link to the right side of my NAVBAR.
Right next to the magnifier search icon.
Basically I need to put a Donate Link Menu.
Thank you so much in advance for your help.

This is the website: [www.clihelp.org](http://www.clihelp.org)

This is the menu code for my NAVBAR.  Please let me know if you need more code.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $config['serv_url'];?>">clihelp <sup>beta</sup></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <?php
                    $Show->show_navbar_menu();
                    ?>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="POST" action="<?= $config['serv_url'];?>">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <?php 
                                    $Show->filter_menu();
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
                                <input type="hidden" name="os_id" >         
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search term...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn" id="search-wrapper">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="search-button" disabled><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `php`. It is a question about using `html`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $config['serv_url'];?>">clihelp <sup>beta</sup></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<?php
$Show->show_navbar_menu();
?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="POST" action="<?= $config['serv_url'];?>">
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<?php 
$Show->filter_menu();
?>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
<input type="hidden" name="os_id" >         
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search term...">
<span class="input-group-btn" id="search-wrapper">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="search-button" disabled><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard : yes you are right sir!!! but the explanation was already there in question. so no much needed to explain in the answer... anyways will keep this in mind for future.

Comment: @prakashtank Thank you so much. Done.

Answer (score 0):

change your html

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="POST" action="<?= $config['serv_url'];?>">
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<?php 
$Show->filter_menu();
?>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
<input type="hidden" name="os_id" >         
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search term...">
<span class="input-group-btn" id="search-wrapper">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="search-button" disabled><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
    </li>
  <li><a href="#">Donate Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.